# how to set conditional bin program creation using autotools

Tags: makefile

I am a beginner in using autotool, I want to add some shell script in the Makefile.am, when I use the method below, the Makefile created by autotool is not I am expected. How can I write to create the correct one.
Thanks for your reply!

PS:
this is my configure.in and Makefile.am(parts)

configure.in:

```
if test "$sample" = yes;then
    DEFS="$DEFS -DSAMPLE=1"
    AC_SUBST(SAMPLE, [yes])
fi
```

Makefile.am:

```
if test "$SAMPLE" = yes;then
    noinst_PROGRAMS = test
    test_SOURCES = test.c
else
    bin_PROGRAMS = release
    release_SOURCES = main.c
fi
```

Makefile autotool created:

```
 ........
 ........
 .PHONY: CTAGS GTAGS all all-am check check-am clean clean-generic \
 clean-libLTLIBRARIES clean-libtool clean-noinstPROGRAMS ctags \
 distclean distclean-compile distclean-generic \
 distclean-libtool distclean-tags distdir dvi dvi-am html \
 html-am info info-am install install-am install-data \
 install-data-am install-dvi install-dvi-am install-exec \
 install-exec-am install-html install-html-am \
 install-includeHEADERS install-info install-info-am \
 install-libLTLIBRARIES install-man install-pdf install-pdf-am \
 install-ps install-ps-am install-strip installcheck \
 installcheck-am installdirs maintainer-clean \
 maintainer-clean-generic mostlyclean mostlyclean-compile \
 mostlyclean-generic mostlyclean-libtool pdf pdf-am ps ps-am \
 tags uninstall uninstall-am uninstall-includeHEADERS \
 uninstall-libLTLIBRARIES

if test "yes" = yes;then
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automake conditionals don't work like that. See the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).

Here's how it should look:

configure.ac:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([SAMPLE], [test "$SAMPLE" = yes])
```

Makefile.am:

```
if SAMPLE
noinst_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = test.c
else
bin_PROGRAMS = release
release_SOURCES = main.c
endif
```